# Displaying all text in one JOptionPane instead of multiple, line by line

Tags: java, swing, text-files, java.util.scanner, joptionpane

(Hopefully) Quick question, I've written out some code to display information from a text file in a JOptionPane, it works, but it's creating a new box for each line.

How would I make it display all read text in a single JOptionPane instead of box by box, line by line. Without having to rewrite the whole thing, if possible.

```
Scanner inFile = null; 
            try {
                inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader( curDir + "/scripts/sysinfo.txt"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DropDownTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    while(inFile.hasNextLine()){
        String line = inFile.nextLine();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, line, "System Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
    }
```

I've looked around for similar questions but couldn't find anything to quite fit this and decided to just ask, but I'll apologize if I've somehow missed something and this ends up as a duplicate.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a StringBuilder to create a single large string, then display this StringBuilder like so:

```
        Scanner inFile = null; 
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(curDir + "/scripts/sysinfo.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DropDownTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        while(inFile.hasNextLine()){
            String line = inFile.nextLine();
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append("\n"); // add this for newlines
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, builder, "System Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Unfortunately all this did was make it add the next line to the previous line in a new box continuously until it reached the end of the file.

Comment: Scratch that, I had misplaced a bracket and after fixing it, all text was displayed. However, it's still not quite what I was aiming for, I'm trying to get it to display as it is in the file, each line under the next, instead of one long line.

Comment: Just add a newline character in on each loop, I'll post it above

Comment: Last time I checked `JLabel` (which is been used by `JOptionPane`) doesn't support `\n`

Comment: I tried this on a JOptionPane just now and it worked fine. The StringBuilder's append method seems to handle it.

Comment: This did it perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to add on another question, but I'd imagine it's pretty simple. This dialogue box pops up after a batch file is ran and it's output dumped into a file. How would I add a little delay before the JOptionPane tries to read the file or just after it runs the batch file? I know how to add delays in batch, Shell, etc just not java.

Comment: That's a threading issue I would imagine, I'm still pretty green as a Java programmer and I'm actually studying that topic as we speak, but unfortunately I'm not sure of the correct answer at this time. It's probably just a Thread.sleep() thing, see if you can figure it out after reading through some of this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Hmmm, from what I see Thread.sleep(5000); just after the first operation should suffice. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Create a String and show that single String after while loop. You are showing JOptionPane in while loop, that's why it's showing output for each line.

```
Scanner inFile = null; 
String message = null;
        try {
            inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader( curDir + "/scripts/sysinfo.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DropDownTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
while(inFile.hasNextLine()){
    message = message  + inFile.nextLine();
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "System Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

This code will print your whole message in single box instead of multiple.

Comment: Isn't that just going to make it a very long line of text?

Comment: @ MadProgrammer Yes, but it goes according to need of the program and how much text will be in the file. And it could be solved by your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, I think we forget just how powerful the `JOptionPane` API is.  The second (message) parameter is an `Object`, if it's a component of some kind, then it's simply added to the dialog, for example...

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);
ta.setEditable(false);
try (Reader reader = new FileReader( curDir + "/scripts/sysinfo.txt")) {
    ta.read(reader, "Some stuff");
} catch (IOException exp) {
    ta.append(exp.getMessage());
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(ta), "System Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

This just makes use of a `JTextArea` (and `JScrollPane`) to display the text from the file.